# C# unbounded generic type as constrain

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints

Is it possible to have a generic constraint which is an unbounded generic type?

For example:

```
public T DoSomething<T>(T dictionary) where T : IDictionary<,>
{
    ...
}
```

---

**Edit:** Just to explain the context, I want to constrain the usage of the method to an IDictionary, but for the method itself it does not matter exactly what TKey and TValue are.

Comment: `public V DoSomething<K,V>(IDictionary<K,V>
dictionary)` Is this what you meant?

Comment: Amir Abiri, why do you want the return type to be the same as the parameter type `T`? Are you going to return the parameter? There's probably no need for that. And you can't easily construct another `T`. Unless you want to constraint `T : new()` as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't possible, you need to specify the type parameters:

```
public T DoSomething<T, TKey, TValue>(T dictionary) where T : IDictionary<TKey, TValue> { ... }
```

Comment: You see the funny thing is that TKey and TValue can be inferred from T and I don't need them anywhere in the body of the method. So I had hoped to make the generic signature cleaner.

Comment: @AmirAbiri - Could you constrain `T` to the non-generic `IDictionary` instead?

Comment: Well actually I used IDictionary only to simplify the example. My real type is "any subclass of BaseGameState<?>" (i.e T isn't an interface, it's my own base class).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. Maybe you can use

```
public IDictionary<TKey, TValue> DoSomething<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in [rosylin github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5023), however, it's not done yet. So it's not possible right now, but I expect it will be relatively soon.